# Access SDL log file on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, sdl-2

I am running SDL (2.0.3) on iOS (9.3) and it's up and running fine - only thing is when I have a runtime exception I can't see it.  From [what I've read](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/FAQ_Console), I think stderr is being redirected to a file but I can't access it.

I've added the UIFileSharingEnabled in info.plist

But when I look using iTunes File sharing, there are no files under my app (I was hoping to see stderr.txt there).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated - have spent a very long time on this without result.

EDIT: Or if I knew what to change in the SDL code so that it does not redirect to a file in the first place but outputs to console then I could recompile the SDL library and solve the problem that way.

Comment: This is an old article addressing SDL 1.2. SDL2 don't redirect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out from version 2.0.4 of SDL running on iOS, output is not redirected but just shows up on the XCode console as normal.